# Json is not validating with file content?

Tags: javascript, json

I have tested my json data with normal content that is working fine.

S**ample data as below:**

## Working Json

```
 {
  "language": "XYZ",
  "content": {
    "GEN": "this is test",
    "EXO": "this is test"
   }
 }
```

## Not working json

```
 {
  "language": "XYZ",
  "content": {
    "GEN": "\id GEN\n\c 1\n\p\n\v 1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.\n\v 2 And the earth was without form and was void form.",
    "EXO": "\id EXO\n\c 1\n\p\n\v 1 Now these are the names of the children of Israel, which came to Egypt; every man and his household came with Jacob\n\v 2 Reuben, Simeon, Levi, and Judah"
   }
}
```

[Check screenshot for working and not working json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA64e.png)

Comment: In your screenshot it appears the problem is that you're pasting two JSON objects consecutively.

Comment: Ok, but I have just attached for information which is working and another is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the escape sequences, you can convert your object into JSON string and then parse like below this

```
 var obj= {
            "language": "XYZ",
            "content": {
                "GEN": "\id GEN\n\c 1\n\p\n\v 1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.\n\v 2 And the earth was without form and was void form.",
                "EXO": "\id EXO\n\c 1\n\p\n\v 1 Now these are the names of the children of Israel, which came to Egypt; every man and his household came with Jacob\n\v 2 Reuben, Simeon, Levi, and Judah"
            }
        };
        var json= JSON.stringify(obj);
```

This will be more simple to you.

Comment: yeah this one is also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The only backslash escape sequences JSON permits are `\b`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t` and `\"`. All other uses of a backslash must be escaped as `\\`. The problem is that `\i` (and some of the other escape sequences) don't mean anything to JSON and are therefore a syntax error. Write it as `\\i` instead.